# R importing csv with comma missing on header

Tags: r, csv

In R, the csv files I import are missing a comma at the end of the header row. I download new files every day so I would like to figure out how to fix the problem in R rather then edit the files each time. Here is an example.

```
head1,head2,head3"dat1","dat2","123","dat1b","dat2b","456"
```

The files appear to have quotes around all data, not just strings. The import method I am using is:

```
mydata <-read.csv('mycsv.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Possibly I can find the first quote and insert a comma before it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Missing a comma, or missing a newline?

Comment: Are the elements of the header also quoted? And is the header the same for all files?

Comment: headers not in quotes, elements are in quotes. I am not sure if it is missing the comma or the newline. How do I check that?  -thanks

Comment: when i open the files in notepad and wordpad both, new lines are not rendered.

Comment: correction - in notepad there is no newline. In wordpad there is, but it is difficult to tell if this happened due to the wordpad application deciding to split the line or what. In wordpad there seems to be something at the end of the line based on using the arrow keys.

Comment: the end of the element 'rows' do have commas though. I just added that. I apologize for not providing all the necessary info.

Comment: Can you upload an example file somewhere (dropbox or something) and include a link?

Comment: Just to be clear, are there _any_ newlines in your csv, or is it just one long comma-separated string that is just missing the comma after the final header element? Your new example above suggests that all rows' data are combined into the header row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but it may suffice.

First, read in whole lines rather than attempting to interpret as csv straight away. Where I've used `textConnection` in this first code block, you can supply a file path or url, e.g. `readLines('/path/to/my/strange.csv')`.

```
tmp <- readLines(textConnection('head1,head2,head3"dat1","dat2","123"
"dat3","dat4","456"
"dat5","dat6","789"
"dat7","dat8","012"
"dat9","dat10","345"
"dat11","dat12","678"'))
```

Then a bit of manipulation of the first row:

```
h <- sub('\".*', '', tmp[1]) # extracts the headers from the first line
row1 <- sub('[^\"]*(.*)', '\\1', tmp[1]) # extracts the first row's data
tmp <- c(row1, tmp[-1]) # combines the first row's data with subsequent rows' data
```

Now interpret is as a csv:

```
dat <- read.csv(textConnection(tmp), header=FALSE) # read tmp in as a csv
names(dat) <- strsplit(h, ',')[[1]] # add headers

dat

  head1 head2 head3
1  dat1  dat2   123
2  dat3  dat4   456
3  dat5  dat6   789
4  dat7  dat8    12
5  dat9 dat10   345
6 dat11 dat12   678
```

Comment: The files have too many headers and they vary so I can't specify the header names. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify header names with this approach. They are extracted with regex. The pattern here takes everything in the first line up to the first `"`, and assumed that constitutes the header. It also assumes the header is comma-separated (without a final comma). Try it and see

Comment: Ok I will try and see, and I'll be sure to get back. Thanks

Comment: you have pointed me in the right direction, because the file is now imported and the header (h) is correct. But I have some problems with the subs, all the data has extra quotes and slashes. I should be able to sort this out, and it is probably be due to my not explaining the file correctly.  I will get back to this post later. Thanks.

Comment: `row1` and `tmp` will look, e.g., like `"\"dat1\",\"dat2\",\"123\""`, but `read.csv` should deal with that and `dat` should look fine. If you're still having trouble let me know and I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: For some reason there was an extra column with NA as the colname and as the data. I just added this at the end: dat <- dat[1:length(names(dat))-1]

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
data=scan(file.choose(),"")
```